# Regex validation for 'Does Not Start With' in MVC

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-5

OK I am trying to use Regex to validate a model property in MVC5.

It's simple enough, the regex is valid as long as the string doesn't start with Aa, Bb or Cc.

My code is below:

```
[RegularExpression("^(?!Aa)(?!Bb)(?!Cc)")]
```

However it is returning everything as invalid, what's wrong with my Regex?

Comment: Add a `.*` to the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex :

```
^(?!Aa|Bb|Cc).*$
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/gA7rX1